# AWS Lambda getUTCMinute avoiding cold start

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that runs every minute to get all my files from S3 partitioned by `"#{folder_name}/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{minute}/#{System.os_time()}-#{file_name}.#{file_ext}"`. As we all know Lambda has cold starts which results in my `minute` to be off constantly. Is there a way I can get the correct minute in my lambda function? For example, if the current minute is `22` but Lambda cold starts at `23`.

```
import boto3
import json
from datetime import date, datetime,timedelta
import _datetime
import uuid

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    keys = []
    #result = []
    utc_today = datetime.utcnow()
    utc_today_delta = utc_today + timedelta(hours=-1)
    folder_path = {
        "now" : int(str(round(time.time() * 1000))),
        "utc_year" : datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y'),
        "utc_month" : datetime.utcnow().strftime('%-m'),
        "utc_day" : datetime.utcnow().strftime('%-d'),
        "utc_hour" : datetime.utcnow().strftime('%-H'),
        "utc_minute" : datetime.utcnow().strftime('%-M'),
        "year_delta" : utc_today_delta.strftime('%Y'),
        "month_delta" : utc_today_delta.strftime('%-m'),
        "day_delta" : utc_today_delta.strftime('%-d'),
        "hour_delta" : utc_today_delta.strftime('%-H'),
        "minute_delta" : utc_today_delta.strftime('%-M'),
        "file_ext" : f"{str(uuid.uuid4().hex)}.json"
    }

    prefix = f"Uploads/{folder_path['year_delta']}/{folder_path['month_delta']}/{folder_path['day_delta']}/{folder_path['hour_delta']}/{folder_path['minute_delta']}"
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my_bucket', Prefix=prefix)
    for page in pages:
        if page.get('KeyCount') != 0:
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                get_object = s3_resource.Object('my_bucket',key = obj['Key']) 
                file_content = get_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
                json_content = json.loads(file_content)
                keys.append(json_content)
    return create_object_path(keys,folder_path,s3_resource)

def create_object_path(get_keys,get_folder_path,get_s3_resource):
    folder_name = f"FE-Uploads/{get_folder_path['utc_year']}/{get_folder_path['utc_month']}/{get_folder_path['utc_day']}/{get_folder_path['utc_hour']}/{get_folder_path['now']}-{get_folder_path['file_ext']}"
    s3object = get_s3_resource.Object('my_bucket_2', folder_name)
    s3object.put(
        Body=(bytes(json.dumps(get_keys, indent=2, sort_keys=False).encode('UTF-8')))
        )
    return None
```

Comment: What makes you think the cold start is the problem? Usually a cold start induces just a few hundred milliseconds of latency, so I'm skeptical it caused by the cold start. It could just as well be that the pagination takes up to a minute.

Comment: @LRutten when I look at the cloud watch logs I see timestamps skip. For example 1,2,4,4.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really related to the cold start period (you can check this if you enable x-ray active tracing for the lambda), the simplest way to improve performance is

1. Use a larger lambda (1GB memory at least). This reduces cold start time significantly.
2. try to set up the s3_client and s3_resource OUTSIDE of the lambda handler (this reduces execution time). So put them just after the imports.

If that doens't suffice, use provisioned concurrency.
To do this, for your latest lambda code, create a lambda version. Enable provisioned concurrency for that lambda version. Since you don't need run concurrently, you can set the provisioned concurrency to 1 or 2 max.  More info on provisioned concurrency [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-provisioned).

However I'm still not sure cold starts are your problem. Looking at [this research](https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-cron) lambda crons very regularly don't execute when the minute starts. Instead, often is starts 40 seconds or more after the minute has started. You can check if this is the case by checking the cloudwatch logs timestamps for invocation. Again, you can check the coldstart time by enabling x-ray (no code changes required). But 40 is still not enough to skip a minute entirely, so not sure what's up with that.

Since you create the path before the time consuming for-loop I don't think the for loop is the issue.

I'd suggest looking into xray and the execution log timestamps to further check what is the issue.